# Solve $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}^TD\mathbf{v})$ for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, bilinear-form

Is there a way to simplify
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}^TD\mathbf{v})$$

to the form

$$f(\mathbf{x})=(I-A)\mathbf{x}$$

where
$\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are column-vectors and $D$ is a matrix?

In particular, I seek to extract the variable $\mathbf{x}$ as a common factor so that it appears only once in the expression for $f(\mathbf{x})$.

I could write $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}^TD^T\mathbf{x})$ but then I still don't know how to get that into the form $(...\text{constant matrix expression }...)\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is linear in $x$ so it can be reduced to such form:

$f(\mathbf{x})=M \mathbf{x}$

where explicitely the components of the matrix $M$ are $M_{a,b}=\delta_{a,b}-v_a (D\mathbf{v})_b$

We can put it in a more vector form, if needed:

$v_a (D\mathbf{v})_b=\sum_c v_a D_{b,c}v_c=\sum_c (\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^+)_{a,c}D_{b,c}=[(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^+) D^+]_{a,b}$

Comment: Would $M=I-\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^TD^T$?

Comment: yes I added that

Comment: How is it easier for people to think of these things in terms of matrix elements than in terms of algebraic manipulations on matrices themselves? Not so much in  this example, but I see this often and I feel there is a perspective on linear algebra that I am missing.

Comment: Usually I tend to write explicitly the components and only at the end summarize the result in terms of vector/matrix multiplications/operations. It helps me to avoid missing parts around, but I am not sure what other people do..

Comment: My first instinct was to just notice that $x^TDv = (Dv)^Tx$ and then in naturally follows.  Just adding how I think about these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Checking with 2 by 2 matrix,
$$f(x)=(I-vv^TD^T)x$$